# Why my code result show up on the debug console ,when usually it appears on the terminal

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

when i run my code, usually the result will show up on the terminal, but this time,it show up on the debugging console. i have tried to change the json console to 'internalConsole'.

**Code**

```
print('test')
```

**Console log**

```
D:\python folder>
D:\python folder>
D:\python folder>
D:\python folder>
D:\python folder>
```

**Debug console**

[image: the debug console]

Comment: How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1. When we click the run button at the top right of VS Code, the code will output the result in "Terminal":

   [image]
2. When we debug the code (click `F5` or click the "`Start Debugging`" button), the "console" setting in the configuration file "launch.json" has three different settings:

   1). `"console": "integratedTerminal",` (default) (Internal terminal of VS Code:)

   [image]

   2).  `"console": "internalConsole",` (Internal Console of VS Code:)

   [image]

   3). `"console": "externalTerminal",`（External terminal of VS Code:）

   [image]

Reference: [console in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_console).